# create a '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, usb-installation

I have a problem with the USB port and mapping to a device.
I see the device as:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices 
International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

---

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

If I look under the /dev/tty* 
I have loads of tty files, but no ttyusb. I have been on the internet for hours to find the solution, no success.

Comment: Look for /dev/ttyACM*, microcontroller and development boards like Raspberry Pi mostly use that driver. /dev/tty* is mostly used on RS232 with DB9 connector

Comment: hi Sergiy, no I only have /dev/tty. I have created the /dev/usb in the past. I cant finf the tutorial anymore

Comment: If your USB-serial device is detachable, then do the following: 1. disconnect it, 2. open terminal and launch kernel log watch with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. 3. connect the device and wait it to be initialized and shown in log. 4. copy and paste relevant lines of the log to your question by clicking [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1148019/edit).

Comment: disconnecting the USB port (the far end of the line) and reconnecting can solve the problem.

Comment: In my case was the cable, after tried with 5 cables the fifth was the one.